# Is there a free competition hosting site?

Tags: photo-galleries, sharing

I'd like to host a photo competition with some of my coworkers, but we have no internal site that would allow voting on photos.  Does anyone know of a site that would allow uploading and voting on photos for free?

Comment: You might get some better answers at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And if you do get answers at webapps, it'd be good to re-post them here, since this is certainly a good photography-oriented question.

Comment: A little bit late but with PollUnit you can create photo competitions. For small teams (< 40) it is free. More infos: https://pollunit.com/en/photo-contest

Comment: https://imgress.com/create is a free image voting platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was in internal company competition and behind the firewall. I was able to download   [TinyWebGallery](http://www.tinywebgallery.com/en/main.php).  Which allowed me to create an easy to use gallery which allows people to vote on the images.

Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you could use [flickr](http://www.flickr.com) for that. You can set a group there, post those photos in this group - this means they are all reachable from a single place.

Although Flickr doesn't support voting on photos directly, in stackexchange style - "upvote"/"downvote" you can post the votes in the comments.

Just my $0.02

---

Edit: I believe it also wouldn't be hard to put together a piece of code that would use flickr-hosted images and allow people to up/downvote on them...

Comment: I've participated in a few set up along these lines in the past...

Comment: Simple up/downvoting of photos wouldn't be that hard, but with more extensive features - scoring out of X, multi-competition league, anonymised voting, and so on - it does get to be a fairly significant piece of work.

Comment: Seems like a nice project to make though... If there are no like this I mean:)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is a commonly used tool for photo competitions - you can judge it based on the number of 'likes' a photo gets. If you set up a new group, restrict it to those you want to enter, and enable photo posting, that should do what you want. Of course this relies on you all being signed up to Facebook...

Comment: Facebook is not a good platform for a Photocompetition or Uploads in anysense. I think their terms of usage force you (like many other big socialnetwork-sites) to give them the right to use it in any way you can think of. Even for advertisments or for sell. I wouldn't accept on this if I shoot a really cool photo.

Comment: I think Facebook changed the terms. I'm no legal expert, but images uploaded to facebook still stay on the server until some undetermined time, but privacy settings apply. So if the image is public for all the view, then FB can use it as part of their advertising. That said, I agree with Greg. I would not use Facebook, simply because of the wacked out privacy settings.

Comment: Gregor - that's just not true. They only say you give them the right to display the photographs on their site - which you need to do otherwise people wouldn't be able to upload photos at all! If the OP creates a private group as I suggested, nobody but the group members would be able to view the photographs. There is a lot of talk about Facebook and the privacy implications - but you still have full control over who can see your stuff, beyond copying and pasting, which is a risk wherever you post on the internet. Still, each to their own; I just suggested a simple option.

Comment: Irrespective of any usage rights, Facebook is an absolutely terrible platform for photo competitions - not least because the photos are shrunk and compressed.

Comment: From Facebook Statement of Rights: "For content that is covered by intellectual property rights, like photos and videos ("IP content"), you specifically give us the following permission, subject to your privacy and application settings: you grant us a non-exclusive, transferable, sub-licensable, royalty-free, worldwide license to use any IP content that you post on or in connection with Facebook ("IP License"). This IP License ends when you delete your IP content or your account unless your content has been shared with others, and they have not deleted it." That's pretty open....

Answer (score 0):

Try www.photoscramble.com this photo contest platform has the best of both worlds. You can find contests from many companies around the world and you can create a photo contest fast-easy and they have a free option.

Comment: Michael, your first two posts are answers to old questions promoting this site. Have you read the part about site promotion in the [faq#promotion]?